# Свойства JAVA

Tags: java

Начинаю осваивать язык java. Интересует вопрос. Какие в java есть уникальные, характерные только для него, свойства и особенности?

Comment: Куча бабок, вложенных sun'ом (ещё когда его оракул не проглотил)

Comment: @carapuz Еще скажите, что вы не ожидали, что сразу же начнется холивар `C# vs Java` :)

Comment: Наивно надеялся, что нет)))

Comment: Вопрос очень мутный.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давным давно, когда @carapuz еще под стол пешком ходил - меня друзья уговорили пойти на лекцию одного чудика про новый язык программирования "Джава". Имя чудика у меня из памяти выветрилось, но помню что он рассказывал про некоего Гослинга без придыхания как о старпёре из соседнего кабинета (видимо так оно и было).

Так вот чудик говорил, что Java язык придуманный для того, чтобы программировать кофеварки, телики, холодильники, тостеры и проч. муть. Собсно и само название говорит о его кофейно-тостерных корнях, поскольку на ам. сленге Java означает сорт дешевого кофе - ну и эмблему кофейную вы тоже наверное помните
[image: Java Logo]. В общем заливал тот чудик долго, много и горячо говорил о его кроссплатформенности о Java машине, о том что скоро все кофейные машины будут оснащаться этой VM и проч. чудеса. Мы в общем послушали, похихикали и пошли по своим делам.

Прошло лет наверное несколько и я услышал опять про этот чудодейственный язык, который вдруг оказался очень крутым серверным языком и все такое.

Я был фшоке и до сих пор если честно нахожусь фшоке.

Возвращаясь к вопросу топикстартера. У Java 1 преимущество: он оказался в нужное время и в нужном месте, а именно рынку нужен был кроссплатформенный язык - тут то и подвернулся язык для программирования кофеварок. Отсюда и другое его преимущество: это самая mature технология обеспечивающая кроссплатформенность. .NET/C# - тупо опоздал на старте - причем лет на 10 и он постоянно находится в роли догоняющего. Надеюсь теперь уже вечно в роли догоняющего.

Comment: Вот-вот. В нужное время в нужном месте. Для меня это единственное объяснение популярности этого громоздкого, тупого, многословного, примитивного и вообще некрасивого языка.

Comment: @mikillskegg, это ты про java? жди небесной кары....

Comment: гы-гы-гы ))))

Comment: @mikillskegg, стоило бы попросить вас подтвердить каждое слово документально да с примерами, в сравнении с вашим любимым, не громоздким, острым, малословным, развитым и вообще красивым языком, но, думаю, что у вас совершенно ничего не получится:) А пустой треп, совершенно бесполезен и не несет в себе никакой смысловой нагрузки. 

Списывать со счетов довольно распространенный язык только потому, что он вам не нравится - как минимум глупо, если не сказать больше. Даже если бы он остался языком для кофеварок, у него есть своя ниша, в которой он преуспел... и отвергать это, повторюсь, глупо.

Comment: @Dex, по поводу

    не громоздким, острым, малословным, развитым и вообще красивым языком

Подозреваю, что такого языка нет (*а очень жаль*), иначе все бы писали на нем.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/144632/

4@mikillskegg

Comment: @avp, понятное дело, просто далеко не каждый может признать, что каждый язык имеет свое место. Хотя, может, @mikillskegg, сможет предложить достойную замену Java, вместо бестолковых и никому не нужных оскорблений. Замену, которую сам придумал, сам сделал и сделал лучше.

Comment: @Goretz, а вот это из ВАшей ссылки мне особенно понравилось

    «Есть всего два типа языков программирования: те, на которые люди всё время ругаются, и те, которые никто не использует.»
Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: Не обижайтесь, братцы.  Я никого не хотел обидеть. Просто... не люблю я ее, ну очень не люблю.

Comment: @Dex Насчёт "своего места". Некто Кирилл Перцев (Москва) так высказался о vb:

     Visual Basic выполняет важную социальную функцию -- трудоустройство идиотов.


@avp "острым, малословным, развитым и вообще красивым языком" -- haskell подходит под описание.

Comment: @alexlz, вот только шибко понятным haskell не назовешь. IMHO его ждет судьба Prolog-а.

Comment: @avp Насчёт "судьбы Prolog-а" не скажу, не знаю и не люблю, но уж больно много их, прологовских диалектов.

А haskell -- там вроде всё понятно, если подумать, только вот при наличии опыта императивного программирования мозги приходится сильно поворачивать. Но зато краткость выражений такая, что перлу и присниться не может.
@Gorets А что за указатели в Алгол-60?

Comment: @alexlz, вот насчет выворачивания мозга я и говорил. Prolog в свое время называли языком машин пятого поколения (они должны были аппаратно поддерживать AI. В Японии (в 80-е) была национальная программа создания этих машин). Но все ожидания, как известно, не оправдались.

IMHO создатель Prolog (хорощий математик) сделал язык под *собственные* мозги и успешно использовать его (думать на нем) смогли, ну несколько сотен таких же математиков.

Comment: @avp Обсуждать пролог в вопросе по java... У изначального пролога масса недостатков, в результате чего появилось много диалектов. Вроде велись активные исследования по функционально-логическим языкам with constraints.
А насчёт мозгов, так в императивных языках есть программа, представляющая набор команд (операторов), в функциональных программа -- выражение, которое надо вычислить, в логических -- набор логических уравнений, которые надо решить. Один из недостатков первого пролога -- перебирал много заведомо безнадёжных вариантов.